# Create lookup field in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, field, lookup

How to add lookup column in List1 and bind it with SomeField from List2, and then fill this lookup column with plain text (only use code)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code to create a lookup field:

```
var list = web.Lists["List1"];    
var targetList = web.Lists["List2"];
var fieldName = list.Fields.AddLookup("My Lookup", targetList.ID, false);
var field = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldName) as SPFieldLookup;
field.LookupField = "SomeField";
field.Update();
```

To update the lookup field you set it to the item ID of the item in the target list.

Comment: If the type of "SomeField" is currency or yes/no, it doesn't work. Selected value of "SomeField" will not be displayed in "My Lookup" item. Is it a SharePoint limitation? If it's not, do you know how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Some field types cannot be the target of a lookup. See SharePoint: Not all column types can be used in Calculated or Lookup columns (http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/01/sharepoint-not-all-column-types-can-be.html)